# How do I express the proportion of filled time slots of a calendar?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I was about to ask an English speaking colleague "how does the calendar occupancy look from a schedule perspective" but then I realized "occupancy" is used for rooms/buildings' actual space and how many persons they can accommodate.

How should I express instead the proportion of filled time slots of a calendar?

Comment: "How is the diary looking?" "How many appointment slots are left?" "What bookings do we still have open?"

Comment: I'm sure an English speaking colleague would understand "calendar occupancy", but they might say "how full is the calendar?"

Comment: I’ve never heard “occupancy” used this way. However, if you use it firmly and in a confident tone, people will think it’s a new management concept. If they look puzzled, say in an apologetic tone “saw it in HBR, sorry”.

Comment: What percentage of the scheduled slots are taken? How busy is the calendar? How many slots have been taken or reserved.

Answer (score 0):

What is the schedule for today? What are the appointments for tomorrow? How many events do we have next week?